# How to make a drop-down field use categories?

Tags: categories, relationships, category-group

I have a field called 'Genre' in a channel called 'Games.' I made my list as categories.

I created a category group called 'Genres' and added all my various genres.

Now, I want to create a field type in the 'Games' channel that is a drop-down. This drop-down should connect to the values I put in the category group called 'Genres'

I can't seem to figure this out, though I could swear I have done this in the past on a project.

Comment: Hi. To get an answer to this question it would help if you could be a bit more descriptive both of what you are trying to do, and about the version of EE you are using (and whether you are using add-ons etc.). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EE5 there is an easy solution: create a channel called "Genres" and put your categories into a field in that channel, then you can [tell EE to populate your Select field using the values from that channel](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/select.html).

There are other options that are more complicated than this - there are (AFAIK) no easy ways to tell EE to populate a select using the content of a category.

HTH